# Compare two active record results along just one column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 3 models - `Items`, `Customizations` and `Property Maps`

`Property Maps` has a polymorphic association with `Items` and `Customizations`

The business logic here is, when listing customizations properties -

1. If the customization does not have any properties, display the item properties in a normal cell
2. If the customization has properties that are different from the item, display the list of properties in a "customized-cell" class
3. If the customization has the same properties as that of the item, display the list of properties in a normal cell.
4. If both, the customization and item have no customization, display a blank cell.

This is my current implementation of the above

```
- item_array = Array.new
- @item.property_maps.wood_only.each do |property|
    - item_array.push(property.property_id)
- customization_array = Array.new
- customization.property_maps.wood_only.each do ||
    - customization_array.push(property.property_id)
- if customization.property_maps.wood_only.present? && item_array.sort != customization_array.sort
    td.customized-cell = customization.property_maps.wood_only.map {|property| "#{property.property.name}"}.join(', ')
- elsif @item.property_maps.wood_only.present?
                    td = @item.property_maps.wood_only.map {|property| "#{property.property.name}"}.join(', ')
                - else 
                    td
```

Is there a way where I can compare the results across a column directly from Active Record? This would save the need for me create new arrays and then compare them.